# Custom SSDL - error 2002: The EntityContainer for the conceptual model specified as part of this MSL does not exist in MetadataWorkspace

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx, ssdl

I need to be able to switch between Vista DB and SQL Server.  I generated my edmx using SQL Server and created a separated SSDL file for Vista DB.  When I update my connection string to use my Vista DB SSDL I get the following error:

```
DataModel.msl(3,4) : error 2002: The EntityContainer 'MyEntities' for the conceptual model specified as part of this MSL does not exist in MetadataWorkspace.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.Init(EdmItemCollection edmCollection, StoreItemCollection storeCollection, IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IList`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection..ctor(EdmItemCollection edmCollection, StoreItemCollection storeCollection, IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IList`1 filePaths)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__4()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadAndCheckItemCollection[T](Func`1 itemCollectionLoader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.<>c__DisplayClass16.<.ctor>b__f()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace, Boolean required)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InitializeMappingViewCacheFactory(DbContext owner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
```

I've tried creating a separate MSL (its just a copy of the MSL used by SQL Server, It didn't seem like there was anything provider specific in there), but that did not fix the problem.  I am referencing the required VistaDB dlls, in fact if I recreate my edmx for Vista DB everything works fine, but it's really annoying switching back and forth that way.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an embarrassing problem.  It looks like I accidentally deleted the csdl part of my connection string.  Added it back fixed the problem